# Differences between these three?

Tags: grammar

1. It *was* the best thing that *could have* happened.
2. It *could have* been the best thing that happened.
3. It *could have* been the best thing that *could have* happened.

What are the differences among these three sentences if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

The first is the normal, idiomatic expression.

The second states that what happened *could* have been the best thing, but wasn't. You would need to follow it with an explanation of *why* it turned out not to be for the best.

Using two 'could have's in the same sentence is just confusing and doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Why do you think 1 does not convey the same meaning as 2? They both are using "could have" for the same "thing" but differs slightly in the placement of 'could have'. Why shouldn't I follow it up with an explanation of why it turned out not to be for the best for 1 ?

Comment: As I said, (1) is what native speakers of English say. Of all the things that _might_ have happened, what _did_ happen was the best outcome.  I told you in my answer what I understand (2) to mean.

Comment: I can show you sources where 2 is used in the same vein as 1

Comment: here, read the 4rth last para of this blog https://www.tampabay.com/archive/1992/08/07/council-denies-liquor-store-in-harbordale-neighborhood/

Comment: https://www.dailyecho.co.uk/sport/19546303.aaron-phipps-paralympics-gold-beyond-wildest-dreams/#:~:text=%22Losing%20the%20funding%20was%20hard%20for%20everyone%20but%20we%20stayed%20together%20as%20a%20group%2C%20in%20many%20ways%20it%20could%20have%20been%20the%20best%20thing%20that%20happened%2C%20it%20made%20us%20hungry%2C%22%20added%20Phipps.

Comment: Exactly. The article states that the liquor store was **not** allowed to open, so its opening can't be described as the best outcome. Someone claims that it 'could have been' the best thing **if it had happened**.

Comment: yes I re-read it and that makes sense, but what about my second link?

Comment: You asked what the difference was and I gave my opinion. Aaron Phipps's remark is his own unusual variant of a common idiom. I suppose he means "It's possible that it was the best thing..."

Comment: is there any source where 1 is always considered as an idiom? I have never seen 1 stated as an idiom anywhere.

Comment: If you are so opinionated about it, why did you ask? Google Ngrams only permits searches on phrases up to 5 words, For 2019, _best thing that ever happened_ is much the most common, _best thing that could have_ shows .000 005 662 8% and _could have been the best_ only .000 000 467 0% (which includes phrases ending in other words such as _best man_).  This is my last word on the topic.

Comment: yes I'm starting to think "best thing that could have happened" is an idiom, logically I can't wrap my head around that sentence, 95% of the times the meaning of "could have happened" is literally opposite to that is in this idiom.

Comment: @KateBunting is absolutely correct here.  They are not the same.  The second emphasizes that something went wrong in an almost-perfect situation.   The listener already knows what went wrong, or expects to be told immediately following.  (The first may imply that the outcome was bad, but could have been worse.)